# Is the HttpSessionState.SessionID Property unique per browser process / tab?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Does each tab in each process have a unique `HttpSessionState.SessionID` per browser process / tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is cookie based (by default), so in most browsers the cookie is shared, and you have the same session across all tabs.

So no, it's usually **not** unique.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything that is?

Comment: @Matt - Not that I know of, 2 browser tabs isn't different than making all requests in a single tab, from the server point of view they're indistinguishable, though someone here might have a clever trick I've never seen....SO never ceases to amaze.

Comment: P.S. If you open 2 browser windows, each in `In-private` mode, you'll have 2 different SessionIDs